# How do I find out if my router is compatible with DD-WRT when it's not in their list?

Tags: router, dd-wrt, firmware

I'm considering flashing the firmware on my router to [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/) this weekend.  I tried to find my router ([Medialink - MWN-WAPR150N](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0044YU60M)) in their router database with no luck.

I'm wondering what key things I should look for to determine compatibility.

Is it safe to assume that a router as popular as this works with DD-WRT?  Since it has 4,800+ reviews I'm tempted to say it is but are there a few key things I should look for to determine compatibility?

Comment: Only routers in their database that they officially support will work properly and *should* be flashed (you can easily brick your router otherwise). Other models, no matter how popular they might be, simply aren't recommended unless someone works on DD-WRT to ensure compatibility with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there isn't a lot of internal memory and may not have a supported chipset.

- Amazon [review](http://www.amazon.com/review/R1B5ANVSBL059V) which person claims no support for dd-wrt
- Request on the [dd-wrt forum](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=691069) for support with no response
- [dd-wrt wiki item](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices#Atheros.2C_Ralink_and_any_other_FAQ) on supported Ralink devices

> These devices have special builds only for using on the respective
>   unit. There exists NO other builds than those in the specific folder
>   for the unit.

dd-wrt targets routers they can support based on chipset and flash memory rather than popularity of the router.

Comment: Here's a guide for device detection: http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-detection